# If $S$ is defined to be a finite set of elements, is the complement of $S$, $S^{c}$ the empty set $\emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $S$ is defined to be a finite set of elements, is the complement of $S$, $S^{c}$ the empty set $\emptyset$? I intuitively cannot understand why this is or is not the case. For example, if $S= \{x \in [a,b]  \mid f(x) \neq 0\}$, is $S^{c} =\emptyset$?  Thank you!

Comment: It depends on where you take the complement.

Comment: If we assume that we are working on the *real line*, the *universe* is $\mathbb R$, and $S \subseteq \mathbb R$. Thus $S^c$ is the set of $x \in \mathbb R$ such that $x \notin [a,b]$ **or** $f(x) = 0$ which, in general, is not empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complement of a set is defined relative to some 'universe'.  If you assume that a set $S$ is to be considered the universe, then if $A\subset S$, the complement of $A$ *relative to $S$* is given by $S\setminus A$.

In your case, if you are assuming that $S$ is the universe, then you are asking whether $S\setminus S=\emptyset$ or not.  This is pretty clearly the case, since $A\setminus B$ is the set of all elements of $A$ not in $B$; $S\setminus S$ thus clearly has no elements.

(Note that finiteness does not come into play.)

Answer (score 1):

What is your universe? Say you are working with the real numbers, if $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ then $S^c$ is an infinite set.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f: \Bbb [a, b] \to \Bbb R$ such that $$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $x = \frac{a + b}{2}$} \\
1, & \text{otherwise}  \\
\end{cases}$$

Then $S = \{\frac{a + b}{2}\}$ which is finite. But $S^C \neq \emptyset$